# Laravel hasOneThrough relationship returns null

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm, has-one-through

I have the following table structure in MySQL database:

```
Products
    id - integer
    name - string
    user_id -string

Users
    user_id - string
    password - string
    person_id - integer

Persons
    person_id - integer
    name - string
    email - integer
```

I am using `hasOneThrough` relationship on Products model to get the details about the `Person`, who is linked through `Users`. The code that defines the relation is as follows :

```
public function product_user()
{
    return $this->hasOneThrough(
        'App\Person',
        'App\User',
        'person_id',
        'person_id',
        'user_id',
        'user_id'
     );
}
```

But I am getting `null` when I try to access the property `product_user`, it is giving me `null` all the time. I cannot change the database structure. How can I define a proper relationship in this scenario ?

Comment: your `user_id` is string, so you did not make any relation on your migrations

Answer (score 5):

I always find the documentation for customized relationships a little bit lacking. I will expand on HasOneThrough here:

Lets say A has one C through B.

This relationship means the following would be our schema:

```
model_a
|  a_id    |    name    |
```

```
model_b
|  b_id    | model_a_id |    name   |
```

```
model_c
|  c_id    | model_b_id |    name   |
```

To write out our relationship explicitly defining the keys:

```
class ModelA extends Model
{
    ...
    
    public function cModel()
    {
        return $this->hasOneThrough(
            ModelC::class,
            ModelB::class,
            'model_a_id', // Key on B that relates to A
            'model_b_id', // Key on C that relates to B
            'a_id',       // Key on A that relates to B
            'b_id',       // Key on B that relates to C
        );
    }
```

So for your case, it won't quite work. You would like to have "Products has one Person through User", but you actually have "Product belongs to User which belongs to Person" which means you need this custom package ([staudenmeir/belongs-to-through](https://github.com/staudenmeir/belongs-to-through)) to add that relationship. You can use it like so:

User.php

```
public function person()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Person::class, 'person_id', 'person_id');
}
```

Products.php

```
use \Znck\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToThrough;

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'user_id');
}

public function person()
{
    return $this->belongsToThrough(
        Person::class,
        User::class,
        null, // PK on products, null === 'id'
        '',   // The foreign key prefix for the first "through" parent model, in case you need aliasing.
        [
            Person::class => 'person_id',  // PK on persons
            User::class => 'user_id',      // PK on users
        ],
    );
}
```